# Wrong route after an unsuccessful resource creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

having this controller:

```
def create
@company = Company.new(params[:company])
respond_to do |format|
  if @company.save
    format.html { redirect_to @company, notice: 'Company was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @company, status: :created, location: @company }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @company.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

does anybody know why, after trying to save a record that doesn't pass the validations, rails leads to the "new" action, but the url displayed in the browser's bar is the route for index (that is, /companies)?

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `create` action happens when you POST to `/companies`. When it fails, rather than redirecting to a new page, it just renders the `new` action in place. This is standard for Rails' REST actions.

You'll see similar behavior when updating a record. The edit form will submit a PUT request to the company's resource (e.g. `/companies/1`) and if it fails validations, it will render the `edit` action in place instead of redirecting to `/companies/1/edit`.